# More easy way for async firestore return function code

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I need to make some methods that get information from Firestore and return this data as a variable. For do that I know the firestore `get()` method it's asynchronous and I need to wait for end for get this result.

Now I'm using code like:

```
function retornaIDCompetencia(ambit, numCompetencia) {
return db
    .collection('CCBB')
    .where('ambit', '==', ambit)
    .where('num', '==', '' + numCompetencia + '')
    .get()
    .then(function (querySnapshot) {
        var id;
        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
            id = doc.id;
        });
        return id;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Error getting documents: ', error);
    });
}
```

And to execute this fuction I need something like:

```
var idcompetencia = retornaIDCompetencia(AMBITS.AMBIT_ARTISTIC, 8);
idcompetencia.then((res) => {
    console.log('id => ', res);
});
```

Is there are a simple way to call this function? Something that doesn't use `then()` method? Something like calling the function and do anything, waiting the results inside the function and not outside with `then()` method.

I still have the same query. There are any alternative and simpliest method for call that function asynchronous and fill a variable?

Comment: It seems that you are looking for the "async await" functionality, isn't it? Its pure javascript code

Comment: It's probably, but I try to do it with async/await and it doesn't work because it's new for me and I think I mistake anything. An example helps me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work. Be aware that you may have multiple documents returned and the array will contain multiple ids.

```
async function retornaIDCompetencia(ambit, numCompetencia) {
    return await db
        .collection('CCBB')
        .where('ambit', '==', ambit)
        .where('num', '==', '' + numCompetencia + '')
        .get();
}

var idcompetencia;
var id;

(async () => {
    idcompetencia = await retornaIDCompetencia(AMBITS.AMBIT_ARTISTIC, 8);
    id = idcompetencia.forEach(doc => doc.id).toString();
})();
```

Comment: This code it returns me 'Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function" message!

Comment: Updated the example

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: idcompetencia.map is not a function :(

Comment: Updated use `forEach`

Comment: The prototype of the `snapshot` does not have map I believe it should have `forEach`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: idcompetencia.forEach is not a function.. Still have the same problem. But i think the problem is that firebase return a promise and I need to do then() for work

Comment: Updated the example one more time

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined.
But anyway in the next example, if u see my first post i need a simpliest method jejeje Not just a complex method. If i want something like this I can use my code, so it work perfectly but I want / need simpliest one.

Comment: It doesn't work for now... Waiting for a good alternative!

Comment: I would recommend learning how promises work and how to properly use async/await. What your actually looking for is unclear.

Comment: Any tutorial suggestion?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises